# Get width of Google Adsense Advert

Tags: html, css, adsense

I would like to add text above my Google Adsense ads that simply states that its an advert. I would like to position it to the above but to the right of the advert like so:

[image: advert]

HTML:

```
<ins class="adsbygoogle" data-ad-client="ca-pub-2839207656593947" data-ad-slot="4097751917" data-ad-format="rectangle, horizontal"></ins>
```

As I'm using a responsive ad unit, the width is not always the same. Is there a way to get the width of the advert to allow me to position the 'advertisement' text accordingly preferably without using Javascript? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Would it work to add a `<p style="text-align:right;">Advertisement</p>` and then wrap ad unit and `<p>` in a `<div>`?